# Android Canvas Image Scaling

Tags: android, canvas, android-image

I m new to android development, currently working on App which is working on canvas and images ...
But i m stuck in middle of the process.

I want to implement such a functionality that user touches an edges of the image and if he/she drags thet image, image will be scaled ..

I googled a lot and more of it but couldnt find any tutorial or Demo s ..

Hope you SO guys help me . Such a functionality is provided by galaxy Note like this below image ..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

If user touch the image at right side and will drag that right side then the below code will scaled the image and draw scaled image.

```
Bitmap bmpImage;
        Rect src = new Rect();
        Rect dst = new Rect();
        src.left = initial_Start_pos_X;  // initial Start X postion of image
        src.top = initial_Start_pos_Y;   // initial Start Y postion of image
        src.right =initial_End_pos_X;  // initial End X postion of image
        src.bottom = initial_End_pos_Y;  // initial End Y postion of image

        dst.left = initial_Start_pos_X;
        dst.top = initial_Start_pos_Y;
        dst.right = Draged_Pox_X;       // Drag X position of image
        dst.bottom = initial_End_pos_Y;

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmpImage, src, dst, paint); // This line will scaled the image according to dst rect. It will take the image from src rect and draw in dst rect. so it will scaled the image.
```

You have to invalidate each time the view when you are dragging the image side. you have to invalidate the view in ONTOUCHMOVE.

So you have to check first, That which side of image is touched by user and dragging then you have to modify the above code. 
Above code will show only scaled image in right side only